# Document (pdf) upload with react native expo and Cloudinary

Tags: react-native, expo, cloudinary

I have the following code where I can pick a document (pdf files) using expo-document-picker, and now I'd like to upload to cloudinary. However, I'm getting an error `[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: <]`. My assumption is that I'm sending the formData incorrectly to the Cloudinary API, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. I did go to the Cloudinary settings and make sure that I enabled pdf and zip files to be uploaded.

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as DocumentPicker from "expo-document-picker";

const cloudName = "example";
const apiKey = "example";

export default function MyUploadScreen({ navigation }) {
const [pickedFile, setPickedFile] = React.useState(null);
const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = React.useState(null);

  const pickFile = async () => {
    try {
      const filePickResponse = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: "*/*",
      });

      if (filePickResponse.type === "success") {
        setPickedFile({
          name: filePickResponse.name,
          type: filePickResponse.mimeType,
          uri: filePickResponse.uri,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

const uploadFile = async () => {

    //Add your cloud name
    let apiUrl = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/document/upload";

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("document", pickedFile);
    formData.append("file", pickedFile);
    formData.append("api_key", apiKey);
    formData.append("upload_preset", "example");

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };

    try {
      const fileUploadResponse = await fetch(cloudinaryBaseUrl, {
        body: formData,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

      const jsonResponse = await fileUploadResponse.json();

      console.log(jsonResponse); // This will be the success response with id, secure_url, public_id, asset_id etc..
      setUploadedFile(jsonResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
};
```

The document is able to be picked correctly. What is going wrong here, that is causing the error with uploading the document?

Comment: Hi, when i console.log(filePickResponse.type) i always get undefined, how did you manage to get "success"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: <]` is returned since you're getting in response HTML and not JSON hence the unexpected token: `<`.

The first thing that could lead to this is the URL you are trying to send the upload request to - i.e. `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/document/upload`. You're using `document` as the [resource_type](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#asset_types) and `document` is not a valid value. You could use `image` or `raw` for PDF files, or use `auto` to let Cloudinary assign the `resource_type` automatically - which for PDFs it'll be "image". PDFs are considered "image" resource_types since you can apply transformations to them.
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/paged_and_layered_media#deliver_a_selected_pdf_page_as_an_image

Secondly, the value of `apiUrl` is a string but you're trying to interpolate the `cloudName` variable there. You'll want to replace the double quotes with backticks.

With those changes made your code could look like this:

```
let apiUrl = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/auto/upload`;
```

I see you're also not using `apiUrl` but you're sending the request to `cloudinaryBaseUrl` - worth double checking to make sure this URL is correct in the above format - or you could replace `cloudinaryBaseUrl` with `apiUrl`.

Separate from this, you'll want to make the following changes to your FormData:

- `api_key` can be removed since it's not required when using [unsigned upload](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#unsigned_upload_syntax)
- `document` is not a valid [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_optional_parameters) parameter and should therefore be removed

FormData can just be:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", pickedFile);
formData.append("upload_preset", "example");
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed `document` to `image` and now it works! I'll double check the other changes you mentioned and make sure those issues are taken care of as well. Thanks for your thorough response!